# Rails 3: Setting up private messaging in my rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am setting up private messaging in my application and was wondering what the best way to do this would be, I have a `message` model that has 2 columns, a `to_id` and `from_id`

I have the association set in the message model like so:

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :recipient, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => "to_id"
  belongs_to :sender, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => "from_id"

end
```

How would i set up the relationship in the `user` model? i want to have a `:received messages` association and a `:sent_messages` Association.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the `:foreign_key` on both sides, like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sent_messages, :class_name => 'Message', :foreign_key => 'from_id'
  has_many :received_messages, :class_name => 'Message', :foreign_key => 'to_id'
end
```

I know Rails 3 has an `:inverse_of` option you can pass as well, but I don't have any experience with that.

Answer (score 3):

Even if this tutorial was made for Rails 2, the logic is still useful:

http://www.novawave.net/public/rails_messaging_tutorial.html